# ASP.net hyperlink tilde ~ URLs not rendering as expected

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink, webforms

Given the following code:

```
var link = new HyperLink();
link.NavigateUrl = "~/manual/subdir";
```

This has started rendering on the site as:

```
<a href="manual/subdir">
```

And not as:

```
<a href="/manual/subdir">
```

As expected.  Is there any web.config setting or other setting that changes this behaviour?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
link.NavigateUrl = Page.ResolveUrl("~/manual/subdir");
```

It will set navigate url relative to the website root.